# Updating data into MySql database using PHP Form

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, sql-update

I hope there is someone who can help me. I'm trying to update data into a MySql database using a PHP form with a textarea. 
As long as I update the database with a random string, which is defined at the beginning of the page, it works fine. But when I try to update the database with the $_POST['text'] I receive from the form, the value in the database is not updated.

I really have no idea what the problem is, so I hope there is someone who can help me to make this work. Please let me know if my question isn't clear enough.

test.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea",
      plugins : 'advlist autolink autoresize autosave link image lists charmap media paste preview spellchecker',
      image_advtab: true
    });
  </script>
</head> 

<body>
  <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","test","abc123","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }                                  

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT content FROM page_content WHERE page = 'Zangpedagoog'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $text=$row['content'] ;
    }    
  ?>

  <form method="post" action="./send.php">
    <textarea name="text" width="100%">
    <?php echo $text ?>
    </textarea>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"></form></body></html>
```

send.php

```
<?php
  $update = $_POST['text'];
  echo $update;

  $random = '123456';
  echo $random;

  $con=mysql_connect("example.com","test","abc123","my_db");
  // Check connection
  if (!$con)
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
  }

  mysql_query("UPDATE page_content SET content=$update WHERE page='Zangpedagoog'",$con);

  mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: First you're using `mysqli_query` then you're using `mysql_query` try to stick with "one", `mysqli_` is better and for so many reasons.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli or pdo instead.  You need to definitely look at prepared statements also, your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: also use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Try adding a semi-colon in your textarea echo'ed PHP, as in `<?php echo $text; ?>` or `<?php echo $_POST['$text']; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's here:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE page_content SET content=$update WHERE page='Zangpedagoog'",$con);
```

You are putting $update directly in the string.
That is very dangerous and stupid, but that's not what you came for.
The thing that is really causing an error, I guess, is the lack of ''s around $update.
Now the value get's directly put into the query, instead of as a string, what I think you want.
Keep in mind that this is very open for SQL injections!
Fixed code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE page_content SET content='$update' WHERE page='Zangpedagoog'",$con);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works! And I know it's open to SQL injections, I was only trying something out, but thank you for reminding me!