# Submit Button To Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have researched a lot and I think my error is something super simple or very hard, either way, this is my first question on StackOverflow.

So when I run this:

```
$query="UPDATE `sales` SET `sales` = '40' WHERE `sales`.`id` = 1";
```

it updates my database just fine but now I try to put this under a submit button and it won't work?

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "TESTTEST", "sales");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("Could not connect to database");
    }
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if ($_POST['update']) 
    {
        echo 'Updating...';
        $query="UPDATE `sales` SET `sales` = '40' WHERE `sales`.`id` = 1";
        echo '<br>Successfully Updated';
    } else {
        echo 'Unsuccessful';
    }
?>
```

It echoes successfully updated then I check back to the database and nothing changed... Hopefully, you could help me! Thank you for reading, James.

First PHP tag is there just not showing on blockquote.

Comment: `mysqli_query($link, $query);` needs to go under `$query`

Comment: Maybe this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257507/updating-data-into-mysql-database-using-php-form] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257507/updating-data-into-mysql-database-using-php-form) can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your mysqli_query under query like this.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "TESTTEST", "sales");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()){

    die("Could not connect to database");

    }

    if ($_POST['update']) {

        echo 'Updating...';

        $query="UPDATE `sales` SET `sales` = '40' WHERE `sales`.`id` = 1";

        mysqli_query($link, $query);

        echo '<br>Successfully Updated';

    } else{

        echo 'Unsuccessful';

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly

```
$query="UPDATE `sales` SET `sales` = '40' WHERE `sales`.`id` = '1'; ";
```

with single quotes

Then the `mysqli_query($link, $query);` part.

Comment: why single quotes for `= '1';` ? along with the added semi-colon.

Comment: single quotes are for what if there instead of 1 u gotta need for a variable ex: $query="UPDATE `sales` SET `sales` = '40' WHERE `sales`.`id` = '".$var."'; ";. And as for the " ; " its up to u bro wether u wanna add it or not cause there are certain possibilities for firing multiple queries in php using mysqli_multi_query("select * from table1; select * from table2;") and if u dont like the answer do what u wanna do.

Comment: Dude if there were any $variables I would have had written that way the way u said. Since there wasn't I wrote as the way asked. But still thaks for ur concern :-)